# can operating systems be a reason for a crash?

Tags: crash, operating-system

im wondering if operating systems can be a cause of a crash, example if I have a code, is it possible for it to crash under windows environment but not on linux? or is this impossible?

Comment: Do you mean *operating systems*?

Comment: yes sorry lol ill edit it

Comment: why do people give me minus when its a legit question? im curious about it, not everyone is born a programmer damn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest example is come code where your intention is to make it platform compatible but your have a bug in your code so it crashes on one OS but not on the other. Pseudo code:

```
if (osIsLinux())
    laodLunixDriver(); // causes an exception
else if (osIsWindows())
    loadWindowsDriver(); // works
```

Note how `laodLunixDriver()` is a faulty function that may cause the program to crash.

Another good option for an OS specific crash is accessing files.

```
ifstream file("c:\\myfile.file");
```

may work on Windows, but crash on Linux.

Comment: man thanks for the answer, maybe its a stupid question but I didnt know this :) now I learned something now and this is what I needed, wish you a good day bro